# How would you find the values in an array that equal the sum a specified number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on creating a basic function that takes in 2 parameters -- array and num.

In the array are a list of numbers and the output could essentially generate 3 results:

1. 0 with no two numbers that equal the sum equal to num.
2. 1 variation of two numbers that is equal to the sum that is num
3. Multiple variations of 2 numbers that equal the sum that is num

I've been working with filter and reduce but haven't been able to produce the desired output.

Let's say I have a nums array of [3,6,9,18] and have a specified num value of 15.

```
var findNumSum = function(nums, num) {
function val(a, b) {
    a + b === num; 
    var es = [a, b]
    return es;
}

var result1 = nums.filter(val); // [3,6,9,18]
var result2 = nums.reduce(val); // [[6, 9], 18]] -- I've been able to isolate the num values but wasn't the result I was expecting. I'm still pretty fresh at this.
```

};

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?  What output were you getting?

Comment: Please, add the code you have developed so far.

Comment: You don't need to use `reduce`/`filter` here, you can do this with a simple `for` loop (well, nested `for` loops).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want to find sums for the number 6. Check the first number of the array, let it be 2. You now want to know if there's a 4 in you array, so you check that. Do this process for all the numbers in the array and remove duplicates.

Maybe this could help ?

Comment: That's a clever solution, probably better than looping and trying to generate all possible sums.  I guess if your `num` was `6`, then you'd loop over each number... if the number is bigger than `6` then you skip it, if it's less than `6` then you subtract and search the array for the difference (there may be multiples)... then just keep looping until you have your combinations of sums.

Comment: Yeah, something like that could be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippets along the lines of the previous suggestions:

```js
const arr=[...Array(25)].map((_,v,)=>v), // create an array with 25 numbers
      findsum=(ar,sum)=> 
        ar.reduce((a,c,i)=> 
          (c>sum || ar.slice(i+1).forEach(v=>
             c+v-sum || a.push([c,v])),a) 
        ,[] );

console.log(findsum(arr,27)) // find all possible pairs that add up to 27
```

Maybe it is helpful to you?

Only if the first condition `c>sum` is false the following `ar.slice(i+1).forEach(...)` will be executed. inside the `forEach()`-callback function the `a.push([c,v])` will only be performed `c+v-sum` is "falsy" i. e. `==0`.